# Testing Ionic2 app on real device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am building an app using Ionic 2 and I am at the stage of wanting to test it on a real device. For now I just want to test it on my android phone. I have enabled developer tools but when I try "ionic build android" or "ionic run android" on windows command prompt, I get this error:

> Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

Where/how do I set the path manually?

Comment: You have the android sdk installed, right?

Comment: I don't think I've installed it. I'll do that!

Comment: You need to install it...in order to build the apk you need the android sdk installed in the same machine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it wasn't already set by the SDK:

For Windows 10 and Windows 8: 
In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)

For Windows 7: From the desktop, right click the Computer icon. Choose Properties from the context menu.

Then:

- Click the Advanced system settings link.
- Click Environment Variables.
- In the section System Variables (or User if you prefer), Click New and name it ANDROID_HOME.
- Enter the correct path where the executable files are located